# How to write word boundary inside character class in python without losing its meaning? I wish to add underscore(_) in definition of word boundary(\b)

Tags: python, regex

I am aware that definition of word boundary is `(?<!\w)(?=\w)|(?<=\w)(?!\w)`
and i wish to add underscore(optionally) too in definition of word boundary.

The one way of doing it is we can simply modify the definition 
like the new one would be `(_)?((?<!\w)(?=\w)|(?<=\w)(?!\w))`
, but don't wish to use too long expression.

Easy Approach can be 
If i can write word boundary inside character class, then adding underscore inside character class would be very easy just like `[\b-]`, but the problem is that putting `\b` inside character class i.e. `[\b]`, means back space character not word boundary.

please tell the solution i.e. how to put `\b` inside character class without losing its original meaning.

Comment: can you post some data and the output you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use lookarounds:

```
(?:\b|(?<=_))word(?=\b|_)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^     ^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/L6Ql2p/1) where `(?:\b|(?<=_))` is a non-capturing group matching either a word boundary or a location preceded with `_`, and `(?=\b|_)` is a positive lookahead matching either a word boundary or a `_` symbol.

Unfortunately, Python `re` won't allow using `(?<=\b|_)` as the lookbehind pattern should be of fixed width (else, you will get *`look-behind requires fixed-width pattern`* error).

A [Python demo](https://ideone.com/bGOANi):

```
import re
rx = r"(?:\b|(?<=_))word(?=\b|_)"
s = "some_word_here and a word there"
print(re.findall(rx,s))
```

An alternative solution is to use custom word boundaries like `(?<![^\W_])` / `(?![^\W_])` (see [online demo](https://ideone.com/la6RKG)):

```
rx = r"(?<![^\W_])word(?![^\W_])"
```

The `(?<![^\W_])` negative lookbehind fails a match if there is no character other than non-word and `_` char (so, it requires the start of string or any word char excluding `_` *before* the search word) and `(?![^\W_])` negative lookahead will fail the match if there is no char other than non-word and `_` char (that is, requires the end of string or a word char excluding `_`).

Comment: It is not working!!     s="aakash_goel"  Not working in this case . Also, i don't wish to make any operation on string like split('_'). I wish to search "goel" in this..

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "not working". Look [here](https://ideone.com/XIEBfo), if `goel` is the search word, it is found alright. And  [the alternative code works well, too](https://ideone.com/5gZM7j).

Comment: Please test my suggestions right, and you will see both are working. Replace `word` with the search word (with the second solution, you can even use `re.escape(word)` if it contains special chars, and it should work: `rx = r"(?:\b|(?<=_)){}(?=\b|_)".format(re.escape(word))`)

Comment: lets say , we have s="aakash goel" and s1="aakash_goel". Now, i wish to make "goel" search succesfully in both s & s1..  So, what i did is modified the definition of \b & it is working too. But i wish to make some short regex for it instead of using it definition.                                                        rx=r"(_)?(?<!\w)(?=\w)|(?<=\w)(?!\w)"+'goel'+r"(_)?(?<!\w)(?=\w)|(?<=\w)(?!\w)".                                                                                           re.search(rx,s)  and re.search(rx,s1)  works sucessfully!!

Comment: My solution works the way you expect. Please make any tests you need, you will see.

Comment: Yup. Using rx = r"(?:\b|(?<=_))"+re.escape('goel')+r"(?=\b|_)"  works correctly.. Thank You Wiktor..

Comment: But can you please elaborate about this regex as first part of regex i.e.  r"(?:\b|(?<=_))"  and third part i.e. r"(?=\b|_)" of regex is not matching .

Comment: Sorry, could you please clarify what you want to know? I explained these constructs in the answer: *`(?:\b|(?<=_))` is a non-capturing group matching either a word boundary or a location preceded with `_`, and `(?=\b|_)` is a positive lookahead matching either a word boundary or a `_` symbol.*